# Tapestry - What is best approach for ordering items from different suppliers

Tags: tapestry

In my application i will have to deal with ordering medicines from different suppliers. I have Supplier class that contains medicines. Those medicines can be ordered by pharmacist user. If i have many suppliers, what is the best way to order medicines from those suppliers?

I was thinking to have one select component that have model property like this: model="literal:supplierID=supplierName, 2=Borko, 3=Richard" , then to add zone component to change list of medicines in grid using ajax - when user change selected item from select component.

The second version of ordering is to have listed all suppliers and to have check boxes next to each supplier for selecting multiple suppliers. When user check one check box then in t:zone component to display all medicines from that supplier including medicines from already checked suppliers.

Tell me if you have any suggestion of how to solve this problem.

Thanks,
Borko Djurovic.

Comment: I don't think you mean `Apache Tapestry`, do you ?!